# how to render output from django view to angularjs app

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django

I have a django view which is called using a angular frontend controller and an image is passed to it,and some processing is done on it and output is generated.now i want to render this output to angularjs app instead of giving it to my template.In other words i dont want to use any templates for rendering this output to user, but do it using angular.

app.js

```
$scope.segmentImage = function(image)
    {
    $http({method:'POST', url:'http://127.0.0.1:8000/image/script_function/', data:{'image': image}})
        .then(function successCallback(response)
        {
            console.log('Image Posted successfully')
        },function errorCallback(response)
        {
            console.log('Image Post failed')
        }
    )};
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def segment_image(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = segment_form()
    else:
        if form.is_valid():
            info = request.POST['info_name']
            output = script_function(info)
            ''' Here i am  calling script_function,passing the POST data info to it'''
            return render(request, 'your_app/your_template.html', {
            'output': output,
      })
    return render(request, 'your_app/your_template.html', {
    'form': form,
  })
'''here info is our image in some format'''

def script_function(info):
    '''here goes my main logic'''
    x=y=w=h=102

    return x,y,w,h
```

Comment: you'll have to refactor the view to return json, and then implement an angular template to render that data.

Comment: @Jason i am reading about returning json formatted output from views but i am new to angular.can you take an example of how to render the output using angular template(like eg. draw a bounding box using the four coordinates x,y,w,h returned by views.py)

Answer (score 0):

use js FormData

```
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('image', image);
```

and post fd